# response caching + if-modified-since for html on asp net core

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-core

I am trying to get caching working correctly for an asp net core 2.0 website. The scenario I would like to setup is as follows

1. User requests home page
2. website builds page and stores in server
       cache (with a long duration)
3. client browser loads page
4. client leaves and returns to page after a few mins
5. client browser sends request with if-modified-since request header
6. website response caching checks if-modified-since header and serves
   cached response (as home page was not modified on server)

In my Startup.cs ConfigureServices I have

```
services.AddResponseCaching();
```

and in Configure I have

```
app.UseResponseCaching();
```

No matter now I set my ResponseCache on the HomeController I cannot make this scenario work

Any ideas..?

**[EDIT]**
**Note this issue is not with static files but only on controller endpoints serving html

More Info on what I have tried**

When I set the responseCache on my controller endpoint it has to have a duration set or "NoStore" (which will disable caching) - eg

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any)]
```

The Duration causes "max-age=60" to be added to my "Cache-Control" response header

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
```

But "Last-Modified" header is not in the response which I believe I must have so that a validation request can be sent to the origin on the next request.

To get my browser to send a validation request the request must have an "If-Modified-Since" header. This will only occur when the previous response (to the same endpoint) has a "Last-Modified" header in the response

Even if I manually add a "Last-Modified" response header, causing the browser to send a "If-Modified-Since" header on the next request, as the request is only sent when max-age has expired on the client (and thus it has also expired on the server) the "If-Modified-Since" request header is ignored

So how should I configure this to get my scenario outlined above to work...?

Comment: works fine for me. give us more information to help.

Comment: @Ben updated to give more details